# Calculating sample size using Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, statistics, central-limit-theorem

How many times do we have to throw a dice to achieve the situation, that the proportion of sixes to all numbers is between $\frac{9}{60}$ and $\frac{11}{60}$ with the probability $\leq\frac{1}{100}$?

This is my solution, that gives a wrong answer.

I know, that number of sixes in multiple dice throws is following the binomic distribution ($n$ is the sample size I need to calculate):

$$
\mu = n \cdot\frac{1}{6}\\
\sigma = \sqrt{n\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{5}{6}}
$$

Based on that, I can normalize the random variable $X$ (expressing number of sixes in $n$ throws):
$$
Z=\frac{\overline{X}-n\cdot\frac{1}{6}}{\sqrt{n\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{5}{6}}}
$$

Now I can use the Central Limit Theorem:

$$
P\left(
\frac{n\cdot\frac{1}{6}-\left(n\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{60}\right)-n\cdot\frac{1}{6}}{\sqrt{n\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{5}{6}}}<
Z<
\frac{n\cdot\frac{1}{6}+\left(n\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{60}\right)-n\cdot\frac{1}{6}}{\sqrt{n\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{5}{6}}}
\right)=0.99$$
$$
P\left(Z<
\frac{n\cdot\frac{1}{6}+\left(n\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{60}\right)-n\cdot\frac{1}{6}}{\sqrt{n\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{5}{6}}}
\right)=\frac{0.99}{2}=0.495
$$

I can look up this value in the standardized normal distribution table and use it to calculate the value of $n$.
$$
\Phi(-0.012)=0.495
$$

$$
\frac{n\cdot\frac{1}{6}+\left(n\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{60}\right)-n\cdot\frac{1}{6}}{\sqrt{n\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{5}{6}}}
=-0.012\\
\frac{n\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{60}}{\sqrt{n\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{5}{6}}}
=-0.012\\
n=0.000595
$$

And that is what seems suspicious. I don't think that i have to throw the dice $0.000595$ times to ensure that the ration of sixes is within a $\frac{1}{60}$ error margin from the mean value with the probability of $\frac{1}{100}$.

Can somebody help me to determine where I am wrong? (Sorry about my English.)

**Edit based on [Doug M's comment:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2313603/calculating-sample-size-using-central-limit-theorem#comment4760906_2313603)**
I made a mistake in the left tailed distribution, It should be:
$$
P\left(Z<
\frac{n\cdot\frac{1}{6}+\left(n\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{60}\right)-n\cdot\frac{1}{6}}{\sqrt{n\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{5}{6}}}
\right)=0.995
$$

With this corrected the result for $n$ seems more reasonable:

$$
\Phi(2.58)=0.995
$$

$$
\frac{n\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot{1}{60}}{\sqrt{n\cdot\frac{5}{36}}{}}=2.58\\
n=119815,2
$$

Which means, the optimal sample size is $119816$, which is more than I expected but sounds more reasonable than my previous result.

Comment: If the the number is within 2 tails 99% of the time, it is to the left of one tail 99.5% of the time.

Comment: So the P(Z<...) should be equal to 0.995 instead of 0.495?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a single die

$\mu = \frac 16\\
\sigma^2 = \frac {5}{36}$

the expected number of sixes in $n$ throws

$\mu = \frac 16n\\
\sigma^2 = \frac 5{36}n\\
\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{5n}{36}}$

The average number of sixes in $n$ throws

$\mu = \frac 16\\
\sigma = \frac 1n \sqrt{\frac{5n}{36}}\\
\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{5}{36n}}$

The expected number of sixes is governed by a binomial distribution.  But, for a large number of throws the binomal resembles the normal distribution.

If $99\%$ are inside of a two tailed distribution, $99.5\%$ are to the left of a 1 tailed distribution.

+normsinv(0.995) = 2.575

For how large does $n$ have to be such that $2.57\sigma < \frac {1}{60}$ ?

$60\sqrt 5\cdot 2.57 < 6\sqrt n\\
500\cdot 2.57 < n\\
n>1288$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't get one thing: Why is the $n$ in the standard deviation of the average number of sixes in the denominator instead of the numerator?

Comment: I have made an edit that I hope makes it a little bit more clear.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I get it. I somehow didn't realize, that its about the ratio of sixes in n throws.